# One liner to remove suffix from files in directory

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

On OSX 10.8, how can I rename all files in the current directory by removing certain amount of character from the of the name? Example:

```
my_img_1@2x.png to become my_img_1.png
```

So only `@2x` part will be removed.

Comment: explain the rule for the part to be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact way to do this depends on your files - for example, are they all PNG files? Do you want to remove `@2x` from all of them? Here is a loop which will remove the 3 characters before the file extension from all files in the current directory:

```
for f in *; do
    echo mv "$f" $(sed -r 's/(.*).{3}\.([^\.]+)/\1.\2/' <<< "$f")
done
```

If all your files are named `[something]@2x.png` and you want them to be renamed `[something].png`, this will work:

```
for f in *; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f%@*}.png"
done
```

This works using [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) - effectively the construct `${var%pattern}` means "take `$var` and remove the shortest string that matches [pattern] from the end of it". So in this case, `${f%@*}` means "remove the last `@` and anything after it from `$f`". Then we append `.png` to replace the file extension which has been removed as part of that operation.

```
$f = filename@2x.png
${f%@*} = filename
${f%@*}.png = filename.png
```

Comment: yes, they are all PNG. I want to remove ALL `@2x` from files within specified folder. So better not to specify each file.

Comment: That was just an example, the `for f in *` command will run for all files in the current directory. I will add an additional command you can use.

Comment: Edited answer, hope that is helpful. Googling "bash parameter expansion" may be more enlightening.

Comment: ah ok, so @* is just wildcard. I thought it's some kind of regex. Great answer, thanks!